# Error 'could not find renderer' on using createOrReplaceTempView

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a tempview, so I can do my modeling using sql.

The libraries I've used:

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext()

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

spark = glueContext.spark_session

job = Job(glueContext)
```

Importing my dataset:

```
tabelao = spark.read.csv('tabelas_fato/consolidado.csv', header=True)
```

Trying to create a tempview

```
tabelao_df = tabelao.toPandas()
tabelao_df.createOrReplaceTempView("tabelao_view")
```

The error it returns is

```
Error loading preloads:
Could not find renderer
```

May you guys help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

**`.toPandas()`** returns a dataframe type of `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.

But **`.createOrReplaceTempView("tabelao_view")`** supports for spark dataframe type `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`.

Before converting **to pandas** you can register as **temp view** and do your transformations and finally can convert **to pandas**.

**`Example:`**

```
tabelao.createOrReplaceTempView("tabelao_view")
#do transformations here and convert to pandas df.
tabelao_df=spark.sql("select * from tabelao_view").toPandas()
```